# Ruby on Rails installation, code giving routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails (and stackoverflow, the whole rails stack, and command-line programming in general).

I installed Ruby 2.1.5 on Rails 4.1 from railsinstaller.org and have been trying to follow the tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I've gotten everything to work except the delete method. After attempting the tutorial, I read a forum that suggested using button_to instead of link_to. This change allows delete to work, but I am unable to generate the authentication box (user can delete without authentication). I know from researching that at least one underlying problem is jquery, but I don't know how to get that working with my project. I tried running `rails generate jquery:install`, and it broke my code beyond repair; I had to restart.

I've inserted the error code below.. I am guessing it must be an error on my part, or an issue with me using Windows. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```css
Started DELETE "/articles/2/comments/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-17 23:00:38 -08
00
Processing by CommentsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"hCfYSLj1BoYcIGFK4bDrfdbBJo2rGT9WC6o0AR42Hn
0=", "article_id"=>"2", "id"=>"5"}
  Article Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."
id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Comment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."
article_id" = ? AND "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["article_id", 2], ["id", 5]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.5ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ?  [["id", 5]]
   (27.5ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articles/2
Completed 302 Found in 60ms (ActiveRecord: 32.5ms)


Started GET "/articles/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-17 23:00:38 -0800
Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."
id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Comment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."a
rticle_id" = ?  [["article_id", 2]]
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (10.0ms)
  Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (95.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 225ms (Views: 220.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/defaults.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-17 23:00:38 -08
00

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/defaults.cs
s"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
all'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
start_thread'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (7.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within
rescues/layout (147.5ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/applications.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-17 23:00:39
-0800
[2015-02-17 23:00:39] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a
borted by the software in your host machine. @ io_fillbuf - fd:6
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `
eof?'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `
run'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `blo
ck in start_thread'

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application
s.js"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
all'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
start_thread'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within
rescues/layout (125.0ms)
```

Comment: are you using asset pipeline if yes try `rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not from your delete method.

I think you don't have this file
/stylesheets/defaults.css

-sorry I can't add a comment.